# $U(1)^{3} $ anomaly, trace of a hypercharge?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, gauge-theory, quantum-anomalies, trace

I have recently found the definition of the $U(1)^{3}$ anomaly as:
$$\mathcal{A} = Tr[Y^{3}]_{L} -Tr[Y^{3}]_{R} $$

Where $Y$ is the hypercharge of the left, $L$ or right, $R$ components. What I don't understand is how is it possible to take the trace over a single number?

Comment: The trace is over the hypercharge of all the fermions in each generation. Ths would be equivalent to tracing over a  ${\bf 16}$ representation in SO(10) GUT.

Comment: What would happen if I just wanted to consider one generation? In fact this is what the text that was considering.

Comment: The ${\bf 16}$ is just one generation. The anomalies cancel in each generation separately.

Comment: I strongly recommend you write down the hypercharges for all fermions in your model (in your question) and detail your problem with cubing and adding them.